# What are Numeric#arg and Numeric#angle?

Tags: ruby, math

I noticed while perusing documentation that the `Numeric` class has a method `arg` with the explanation "Returns 0 if the value is positive, pi otherwise. Directly above this in the docs is a method called `angle` which has the same explanation.

I don't understand the purpose of this method, nor why there are two seemingly identical methods, and could not find any info on them.

Comment: There's also Numeric#phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are synonyms.

[`Complex#angle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Complex.html#method-i-angle) return the angle between the x-axis and a line from the origin to complex.

```
Complex(1, 1).angle
# => 0.7853981633974483    # π/4
Complex(0, 1).angle 
# => 1.5707963267948966    # π/2
```

For non-complex numbers, returns π for negative numbers, 0 otherwise. (Because all non-complex numbers are on x-axis)

```
1.angle
# => 0
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add that arg is short for argument: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28complex_analysis%29

Comment: Ah, has to do with complex analysis. That makes it clearer. Still seems odd that it's a method of Numeric then and not of Complex.

Comment: @Aerovistae: Not really. All real numbers (and integers and rationals and...) are also complex numbers after all.